# Is it possible to let nginx serve static files from a zip archive?

Tags: nginx, deployment

I am looking for a solution to distribute a webapp as a single deployable. Analogous to the way you deploy java webapps in an app container - a war file (which is actually a zip file).

So instead of copying an entire tree of website assets I want to put one zipfile in the document root and let nginx extract files from that file as needed.

Comment: I would recommand to take anything related to deployment out of any tool you are using and set up a common delivery process managed by a third party application that could be smarter and look at the whole picture (i.e. the whole infrastructure) rather than trying to reproduce everywhere a particular workflow available in one tool.

Comment: I decided to use rsync to ensure my entire tree is synced properly and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, [nginx-unzip-module](https://github.com/youzee/nginx-unzip-module/blob/master/ngx_http_unzip_module.c) on github does what you're asking.

But I wouldn't use it; reading the source I can already see that it only supports a text/plain mimetype. There might be other problems too; I only glanced through it. While you could probably modify the code to handle additional mime types and even other archive formats, it's not necessarily a thing you want to do.

I'd say you should just distribute as an archive and include unpacking as part of your standard deployment scripts and/or deployment SOP.